# .htaccess will only redirect and not rewrite

Tags: apache, codeigniter-3, .htaccess

I want to rewrite example.com/foo to example.com/index.php?bar (PHP codeigniter).

All files are on the same domain.

As a starting point and to prove setup, the following code succesfully redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^foo/$ https://example.com/index.php?bar [L,QSA,NC]
```

But I want to rewrite and Not Redirect. I have been unable to work out how to do this. I have tried the following for the RewriteRule:

```
#These don't work
RewriteRule ^foo1/$ index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^foo2/$ /index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^foo3/$ index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^foo4/$ /index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^foo5/$ index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,PT]
RewriteRule ^foo6/$ /index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,PT]
RewriteRule ^foo7/$ https://example.com/index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,PT]
```

Full .htaccess is here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^foo/$ https://example.com/index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC]    #works but redirects
RewriteRule ^foo1/$ index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^foo2/$ /index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^foo3/$ index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^foo4/$ /index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,P]
RewriteRule ^foo5/$ index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,PT]
RewriteRule ^foo6/$ /index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,PT]
RewriteRule ^foo7/$ https://example.com/index.php?/bar [L,QSA,NC,PT]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the `/bar` URI on a different domain?

Comment: /bar is on same domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking too complex. Keep things simple:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?foo/?$ /bar [END]
```

The redirection from http to http should be done first, independent from the internal rewriting. You need to keep that separate.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: RewriteRule ^/?foo/?$ /bar/ [QSA,L]   #works
RewriteRule ^/?foo2/?$ /bar/ [QSA,L] #works
RewriteRule ^/?foo3/?$ /index.php/ [QSA,L]    #doesn't rewrite properly
RewriteRule ^/?foo4/?$ /index.php?/offers [QSA,L]  #doesnt rewrite properly

Comment: My problem is to do with codeigniter. This solution works

Comment: New question now posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170064/htaccess-rewrite-url-does-not-work-with-codeigniter-code